# Swift - How do I count the items in an array of a specific value?

Tags: arrays, swift, count

I have an array with 200 items. These are either true or false:

```
let shouldMascotChangeVotes: [Bool] = [false, false, false, true, false, true, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, true, false, false, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, false, false, true, false, true, true, false, false, true, false, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, false, true, false, true, true, false, false, false, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, false, true, false, false, true, true, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, false, false, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, true, false, false, false, true, false, true, false, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, false]
```

I know how to count the total items in the array but I need to be able to count just the true or false values in the array. How do I do that?

```
shouldMascotChangeVotes.count // returns 200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how important the actual performance to you, but you can do such thing, for instance.

```
import UIKit

let shouldMascotChangeVotes: [Bool] = [false, false, false, true, false, true, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, true, false, false, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, false, false, true, false, true, true, false, false, true, false, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, false, true, false, true, true, false, false, false, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, false, true, false, false, true, true, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, false, false, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, true, false, false, false, true, false, true, false, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, false]

let countableSet = NSCountedSet()

shouldMascotChangeVotes.forEach { (item: Bool) in
    countableSet.add(item)
}

debugPrint(countableSet.count(for: true)) // 125
debugPrint(countableSet.count(for: false)) // 75
```

---

*NOTE: maybe not the most effective solution but it does the job; that snippet is coming from Playground directly.*

Comment: Looks like you are drawing on some older Objective-C code? When I try and run this in Playgrounds I get an error. Is there something in Swift that would work in this situation?

Comment: wot? that is the latest _Swift_ and working like the charm – I pasted from my Playground just right now; add `import UIKit` if you have deleted that line.

Comment: holex, yes adding the import UIKit made the difference. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

```
shouldMascotChangeVotes.filter{$0 == true}.count
```

you can filter it first and then count it.

Comment: Hi TPN. If I run that I get the following results: (201 times). Something isn't quite right on that.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code but you could simplify using `{ $0 }`.

Comment: yes i know :) but i figure I would leave it there just to convey the solution better. But yes you're right it can be just       { $0 }

Comment: @fmz this should work, maybe double check the array? I just ran this code and it works like a charm for me

Comment: perfect, you can also use `{$0}` for `true` or `{!$0}` for `false` like mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using reduce(). I did it twice for presentation purpose. You can actually use total count and do a difference.

```
let shouldMascotChangeVotes: [Bool] = [false, false, false, true, false, true, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, true, false, false, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, false, false, true, false, true, true, false, false, true, false, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, false, true, false, true, true, false, false, false, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, false, true, false, false, true, true, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, false, false, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, false, true, true, true, false, false, false, true, false, true, false, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, false]

var trueFalseCount: (trues: Int, falses: Int)

trueFalseCount.trues = shouldMascotChangeVotes.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1 ? 1 : 0) }
trueFalseCount.falses = shouldMascotChangeVotes.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1 ? 0 : 1) }

print(trueFalseCount) // (trues: 125, falses: 75)
```