# swift: count recurring values in a dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, count, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary that is `[uid: true, uid: false, uid: false, uid: false]`. How do I, in Swift, count the number of `true` and `false` values so that I can see that there is 1 `true` and 3 `false` in this dictionary?

Comment: A dictionary cannot have the same key multiple times, so the example you're giving is impossible in Swift.

Comment: I'm assuming that the 'uid's are placeholders for lots of different unique ids?

Comment: @deanWombourne Yes, the 'uid' value is a placeholder. This would be what it actually is: 65vsFeX5y9R69YuvltgS1dL6pFN2

Comment: If you use `myDict.map{ $0.1 }`, then you have an Array of booleans (`[Bool]`). Then, it's just like that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784112/swift-how-do-i-count-the-items-in-an-array-of-a-specific-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to use a construct designed for this purpose: a counted set. There is no native Swift counted set, but you can use `NSCountedSet`.

A counted set works exactly like a set, but it counts how many times you add an element to it.

```
let dict = [
    "key1": true,
    "key2": true,
    "key3": false
]

let countedSet = NSCountedSet()
for (_, value) in dict {
    countedSet.add(value)
}
print("Count for true: \(countedSet.count(for: true))")
```

Comment: This worked best for what I need to do with the data. Thank you for your time and your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `filter` method to remove values you don't want, and then just call `count` on the result.

```
// Get the count of everything which is true
let trueCount = dict.filter { $0.value }.count

// Get the count of everything which is false
let falseCount = dict.filter { !$0.value }.count

// A more efficient way to get the count of everything which is false
let falseCount = dict.count - trueCount
```

Comment: This creates a new dictionary (the result of the filter method) each time you do it, so it's not the most efficient answer in the world :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use high order function like `reduce` :

```
let trueFalstDict: [String: Bool] = ["id1": false, "id2": true, "id3": false, "id4": false]

var trueFalseCount: (trues: Int, falses: Int)

trueFalseCount.trues = trueFalstDict.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.value ? 1 : 0) }
trueFalseCount.falses = trueFalstDict.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.value ? 0 : 1) }

print(trueFalseCount) // (trues: 1, falses: 3)
```

Using @deanWombourne's suggestion:

```
let trueFalstDict: [String: Bool] = ["id1": false, "id2": true, "id3": false, "id4": false]

var trueFalseCount: (trues: Int, falses: Int)

trueFalseCount = trueFalstDict.reduce((trues: 0, falses: 0)) {
    return (
        true: $0.trues + ($1.value ? 1 : 0),
        false: $0.falses + ($1.value ? 0 : 1)
    )
}

print(trueFalseCount) // (trues: 1, falses: 3)
```

Comment: What about in one pass? `dict.reduce((trues: 0, falses: 0)) {
    return (true: $0.trues + ($1.value ? 1 : 0),
            false: $0.falses + ($1.value ? 0 : 1))
}`

Comment: @deanWombourne yes that definitely works for a one liner.

Answer (score 0):

Example setup:

```
let dict = [
    1: true,
    2: false,
    3: false,
    4: false
]
```

Using `NSCountedSet`:

```
let numTrue = NSCountedSet(dict.values).count(for: true)
let numFalse = dict.count - numTrue
```

Using `reduce`:

```
let numTrue = dict.values.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1 ? 1 : 0) }
let numFalse = dict.count - numTrue
```

Both approaches make use of the fact that the `Bool` only allows two different values, allowing a simple calculation of e.g. the `false` count given that you have computed the `true` count (or vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
var currencyDB:[(name: String, value: Double, isShows: Bool, isMain: Bool)] = 
[("USD",1.1588, true, true), 
("JPY",129.30, true, false), 
("BGN",1.9558, true, false), 
("CZK",25.657, true, false), 
("DKK",7.4526, false, false), 
("GBP",0.8905, false, false)]

print(currencyDB.map{ $0.2 }.filter { $0 }.count))  // print: 4 -> trues
print(currencyDB.map{ $0.2 }.filter { !$0 }.count)) // print: 2 -> falses
```